# A determinant identity for sum of positive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-matrices

I'm reading an article where, at some point, the following Identity is used:

$$|\det(C^{+}-C^{-})_{S}| =|\sum_{I\subset S_{1}}\sum_{J\subset S_{2}}\pm\det C^{+}_{I\times J}\det C^{-}_{(S_{1}\setminus I)\times (S_{2} \times J)}|$$
where $C=C^{+}-C^{-} $ is an  $n \times n $ matrix with $C^{\pm} $ both positive-definite and non-degenerate, $S=S_{1}\cup S_{2} $ is an union of disjoint even sets and $C_{S} $ denotes the submatrix $(c_{ij})_{i,j \in S} $ . Now, does anyone know what identity is this? It seems some sort of Cauchy-Binet formula but for a sum rather than a product of matrices. How to prove it?

Comment: Please say what you mean by "$C$ is positive" : is it "all entries of $C$are $>0$", or a positive definite matrix ($X^TCX > 0$ for all $X \neq 0$) ?

Comment: Right, I will edit it!

Comment: I assume $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint, and the sum is only over pairs $\left(I,J\right)$ satisfying $\left|I\right| = \left|J\right|$? This looks like a version of [the standard formula for $\det\left(A+B\right)$ in terms of products of minors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135321/abtract-explanation-for-detab-%e2%88%91-k-0n-langle-lambdak-a-lambdan-k), except that you are missing some $\pm$ signs in the sum.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I will edit it! Thank you!